# Vote Early, Vote Often

Tags: discussion, questions, voting, notifications

Jeff Atwood post new article about voting. Read: [Vote Early, Vote Often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).

Voting is the secong thing most important to SE sites. Don't waste your votes and incentive new user to vote.

Jeff also post an article about [Asking Better Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/). Please read and help us enforce the quality of questions.

- if you see a great, thoughtfully asked, well researched question, vote it up — please! Great questions are an art!
- if you see an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended question that you feel was asked in bad faith … vote it down.
- anything in between that’s salvageable, edit it — if you have the requisite 1,000 reputation.

Please **use your votes**.

Quoting RobertCartaino from chat:

> Vote, vote, vote. Encourage others to vote, vote, vote. On good content, leave signposts ("If you like this, please vote it up. It's important for the community!")-- in both meta and the main site. Maybe a few meta posts informing the users of the important of that type of participation. You are empowered a lot more than you know.

Answer (score 4):

Agreed, I used all my votes yesterday to get some rep into the site.

Answer (score 3):

And especially look for new users' questions/answers to vote up. They're much more likely to stick around if they get some nice fast positive reinforcement.

One easy way to do this is to use https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review

Comment: I agree about voting up quality content from new users. We want to encourage quality from the very start so that new users (like existing ones) know that their good contributions won't be wasted. I don't agree with simply voting up whatever new users post, though (not that you necessarily meant this). New users may need more guidance with respect to the FAQ and meta content, but we don't want to reward bad content just because it comes from new people.