# Vote Early, Vote Often!

Tags: discussion, badges, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote Early, Vote Often](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/vote-early-vote-often)

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/

Just a friendly reminder.  Recently our Q/A rate has been stable, traffic is a bit up, but voting is a bit down.

We need more medium to high rep users of this site to help govern it.  Please consider voting (up or down) any questions and answers that you find helpful.

There are also a [couple](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/57/suffrage) [badges](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/58/sportsmanship) that you could earn while doing so!

Comment: Nothing like writing an exact duplicate, THEN clicking on the voting tag to see what the other question with that tag was....d0h